# J2EE : how to get in servlet an arraylist, passed in hidden field in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I search how to get my arraylist, passed in hidden field in my JSP, in a servlet in a new arraylist.
In my JSP :

```
    <input type="hidden" name="listHidden" id="listHidden" value="${myList}"/>
```

In my servlet, I tested this :

```
    String[] elementsList = request.getParameterValues("listHidden");
```

But the result is my list in the first element of the new table and I need a copy of the arraylist in a new arraylist because I have a treatement to do on the elements of my list.
What is the right code ?

Comment: Have you viewed the source of your generated HTML? What is the value of of `listHidden` in HTML?

Comment: listHidden is an ArrayList<String> build in a first servlet, displayed in  my JSP and I passed it in input hidden in order to get it in a second servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `listHidden` is an `ArrayList<String>` then you should be able to parse the input like,

```
String str = "[string1,string2]";
            // ^--  or, request.getParameter("listHidden").toString();
String[] elementsList = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split("\\,");
```

It might be better to store these values in the `Session` or in a database. Adding them to the form makes that request slower.

Comment: Thanks for this code but when I displayed the elements of this table, I have this for the first element : "[string1". The elements can't be recover as such real elements of a table ?